# POST request SNS publish message (no aws-sdk)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, push-notification, publish-subscribe

I tryed to follow the amazon documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html

but the request response is ever:

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://sns.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-03-31/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidClientTokenId</Code>
    <Message>The security token included in the request is invalid</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>********</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

What is the error? Isn't the signature correct? What is the right way to send a correct POST request?

This is my code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto-js');
var request = require('ajax-request');

AwsValues = {
    accessKey:"**********",
    secretKey:"**********"
    region:"eu-central-1",
    targetArn_iOS:"arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:*************:endpoint/APNS_SANDBOX/*******************"
};

var message = {
    default: 'default',
    APNS_SANDBOX: {
      aps: {
        alert: 'Hello World',
        sound: 'default',
        badge: 1
      }
    },
    APNS: {
      aps: {
        alert: 'Hello World',
        sound: 'default',
        badge: 1
      }
    }
  };

  message.APNS_SANDBOX = JSON.stringify(message.APNS_SANDBOX);
  message.APNS = JSON.stringify(message.APNS);
  message = JSON.stringify(message);


function hmacSHA256(string, key) {
  return crypto.HmacSHA256(string, key).toString(crypto.enc.Base64);
} 

var timeStamp = (new Date()).toISOString(); 
var targetArn = AwsValues.targetArn_iOS;
var awsAccessKeyId = AwsValues.accessKey;
var key = AwsValues.secretKey;

var params = 
"AWSAccessKeyId=" + awsAccessKeyId + "&" +
"Action=Publish" + "&" + 
"SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256" + "&" +
"SignatureVersion=2" + "&" + 
"Timestamp=" + encodeURIComponent(timeStamp) + "&" + 
"Version=" + "2010-03-31";



var url = "sns.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com";

var sign = "POST\n" + url + "\n" + "/\n" + params;

var signature = encodeURIComponent(hmacSHA256(sign,key));



url = 
"http://" + url + "?" +
params + "&" +
"Signature=" + signature + "&" +
"Message=" + encodeURIComponent(message)+ "&" +
"TargetArn=" + encodeURIComponent(targetArn) + "&" + 
"MessageStructure=json";


request({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST', 
    }, function(err, res, body) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(res);
        console.log(body);

        console.log("url\n",url,"\n");
        console.log("sign\n",sign,"\n");
        console.log("signature\n",sign,"\n");

    }
);
```